# Utilizar código dentro de else después de cumplirse primera condición

Tags: python, python-3.x

El código original es más largo pero con el siguiente se comprende lo que quiero lograr:

```
p = True
if p == True:
    print("Just")
    print("Beat")
    #Pero quiero imprimir "It" tambien sin necesidad de copiar y pegar la linea de código
else:
    print("It")
```

Lo que busco es que cuando la primera condición además de ejecutarse el código en dicho bloque, se ejecute el que está dentro del else, sin embargo, cuando en un principio no se cumpla la condición, solo se ejecute el else. En resumen, quiero que cuando se cumpla la condición se ejecute todo el código, pero que cuando no se cumpla, solo se ejecute a partir de cierta parte, siento que no debo utilizar condicionales en este caso, pero no se muy bien como llevarlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solo debes sacar esa instruccion fuera del bucle

```
p = True
if P == True:
    print("Just")
    print("Beat")
else:
    pass
print("It")
```

eso se puede simplificar asi:

```
p = True

if P:
    print("Just")
    print("Beat")
print("It")
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes tener dos `if` y la condición la cambias en el primer `if`:

```
p = True
if p == True:
    print("Just")
    print("Beat")
    p = False

if p == False:
    print("It")
```

Si solo es `false` imprimirá `It`.

Comment: Dado que no conozco Python, pregunto: ¿los nombres de variable son case insensitive en dicho lenguaje? ¿Es lo mismo `P` y `p` en este caso? En cuanto a la pregunta, quizá un ternario sería útil aquí.

Comment: Tienes razón. Se debería corregir el código original.

Comment: Lo probé yo mismo, P y p no son lo mismo en python.

Comment: Listo, corregido.